# Do the eigenvalues of the product of a positive diagonal matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix still have zero real part?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with real, positive entries on the diagonal. Further, let $B$ be a $n\times n$ invertible, skew-symmetric and real matrix. Now let $n$ be even. Then it is known that the eigenvalues of $B$ all have zero real part.

> Is this also true of the product $AB$?

I tried doing some simulations in Matlab: The real parts were not zero, but always $\sim 10^{15}$ times smaller than the imaginary parts, so I suspect this is a rounding error on Matlabs part. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the (symmetric) root of $A$. Then, $AB$ and $RBR$ are similar and we have 
$$ (RBR)^T = RB^T R = -RBR. $$
That is, $RBR$ is skew-symmetric too. In particular the eigenvalues of $RBR$ are imaginary (including zero) and the same as $AB$.

Comment: "Symmetric root"? It's diagonal with positive entries, just call it a square root...

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician square root for matrices is ambiguous. Symmetric root not

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had it, but what can I say about the eigenvalues of $RBR$? I know $B$ and $RBR$ are congruent, but when $B$ is not symmetric, I don't know how to proceed (if it was I could use Sylvester's law of inertia). I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: @Lovsovs, the terminology is admittedly muddled here. To be explicit: try performing a similarity transformation. with $\mathbf A^{-1/2}$, which is equivalent to taking the inverse square root of the diagonal entries of $\mathbf A$.

Comment: @Lovsovs I expanded the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user251257 Indeed it did, thank you for your time!